# Android -- Layout ellipsize with right-aligned view

Tags: android

How can I achieve this as Text1 gets longer?

|[Text1] [Text2]***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**|

|[Text1 Text1 Text1] [Text2]***_*___**|

|[Text1 Text1 Text1 Tex...][Text2]|

Text2 should always be on the right of Text1, but when Text1 is too large, it is ellipsized and Text2 is right-aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a scenario where I needed to have it like this (pretty similar to the OP)

`[[TextView1][Icon]_______[TextView2]]`

`[[TextView1 long..][Icon][TextView2]]`

So the `TextView1` can have arbitrary length and should be ellipsized if it can't fit any more, but the `Icon` should be right next to it and the `TextView2` should always be right-alighned

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        .... />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/Icon"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        .... />

                </LinearLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                .... />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="bbbbb"
        android:textSize="30dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just an FYI, if you set `android:singleLine="true"`, there's no need to add `android:ellipsize="end"` as it will automatically do this.

Comment: I actually opened this up for a different issue (I thought it was the same issue as this). Therefore, this is the right answer. But I opened up the bounty on the wrong question. =(

Answer (score 1):

You should use RelativeLayout Like this ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:text="@string/radio_group_1"
    android:ellipsize="end" android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/txt2"/>
<TextView android:text="@string/Pink_Floyd" android:id="@+id/txt2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Actually, this is what I already had.  The problem is that, in your example, txt2 is always aligned to the far right.  I'm wondering if it's possible, short of doing programatically, to have txt2 just to the right of the first textview.  Once the first textview is too long to fit txt2 inside the parent it is aligned right and the first textview is ellipsized.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Tv1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TV2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="BBBBBBBBBBB"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```